# MEDIA_MOUNTED broadcast not being received

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent

I'm baffled. I'm trying to configure my app to respond to the SD card becoming available / going offline, but my broadcast receiver never gets called!

I can see the event being broadcasted, and other apps responding:

```
08-21 23:43:04.405: DEBUG/Ringer(275): -- intent.getAction() =android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
```

And my manifest has the receiver declared:

```
    <receiver android:name=".Test" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And my receiver has an onReceive method:

```
public class Test extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("#########", "##############################################################");
        Log.d("#########", "Obligitory snarky and/or funny logging comment...");
        Log.d("#########", "##############################################################");
    }
}
```

Yet the &^%$'ing thing won't cause Test.onReceive() to fire. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't be serious. Apparently I needed to add an additional filter for the data type.

Leaving the answer up for "the next guy"...

```
<receiver android:name=".Test" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Looks like the official docs are missing the scheme, which is certainly annoying since their code won't actually work.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: For people linking receivers dynamically you can call addDataScheme("file") on your IntentFilter instance.

Answer (score 7):

You try adding the `<data android:scheme="file" />` tag in the `<intentfilter>`, else do the registration at run time.
At run time, create an object of your broadcast receiver and pass it to `registerReceiver(obj)`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out a few minutes before you posted.

Comment: Then You should add this to the answered questions list.

Comment: Umm, it is... and was, before you even submitted an answer. You added an answer about 15 minutes after I did.

Comment: I am not asking you to tick my answer. tick your answer, so that there is one less unanswered in the questions list.

Comment: Pro Tip: You can't select your own answer on StackOverflow for several days after you submit it.