# External device/USB support in android API level 10

Tags: android

I am an android UI developer and having problem with issue with USB and external storage device support on android. What I want to have is on plug-in USB/SD card, the storage items in the devices directly show up on screen. For example the modern Operating systems have this feature that we plug in our device and it just automatically shows the contents of the device on new window. I am implementing my UI on android API level 10 and my device is IMX reference kit which has android 2.3.4 installed.

I would be grateful if anyone could give specif suggestion or guideline. I already tried with external_storage.java class. but it only says that the APK is installed successfully. But no action launches on plug-in external device.

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively easy: you need to intercept [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` event. And then inflate smth like dialog or message box.

**Update:** 
code to receive broadcast can be found for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142987/media-mounted-broadcast-not-being-recieved)

Comment: Could you please post me the code and guide line to use the code for this purpose? Cause I tried this and plugged in external device, still android did not show me anything. Thanks in advance